# Cascading dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, spservices, list-form

I am trying to get cascading dropdowns to work on a list, but I seem to be missing a point somewhere. Please help me out.

I have added jQuery and jquery.SPServices to my masterpage.

The dropdown should eventually cascade 3 source lists in a 4th list "Orders":

1. Categories (Columns: Title)
2. SubCategories (Columns: Title | MainCategory)
3. Items (Columns: Title, SubCategory)

SubCategories has a lookup column to the Title column of Categories.
Items has a lookup field to SubCategories.

In the NewForm.aspx in my Orders list I have added this code:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function() { 
                        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
                           //Name of list correct
                           relationshipList: "SubCategories",
                           //Name of Column correct
                           relationshipListParentColumn: "MainCategory",
                           relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                           childColumn: "SubCategory",
                           debug: true
                        });

                  });
            </script>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
```

I have two questions regarding this: 
 1. Why does it not work and how to rectify it? 
 2. Where can I place this code, so I do not need to repeat it in the editForm.aspx?

/EDIT:
Is it possible, that I have this code just in the wrong place for it to work?
It is located in the newform.aspx of my Orders list, but references the SubCategories list. I am not sure about this, since the documentation does not cover this point clearly.

Comment: What does not work about it? do you get errors from the debug or are you getting javascript errors in the console?

Comment: No error at all. No debug message - nothing. If I use the list GUID as the relationshipList: variable I am getting a internal Server error, but thats it. I've appended an `alert('foo')`; aber the SPCascadeDropDown() function call, which works. But the cascading itself does not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the "parentColumn" option also? This is something I tried a while ago and wrote some comments that may be helpful.

```
 //State - County Dropdown list
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "County", //Top List County and States columns
relationshipListParentColumn: "Title", //State column in the Top List
relationshipListChildColumn: "County", // County column in the Top list
parentColumn: "State", //Display name in the web part (From the State list)
childColumn: "County" //Display name in the web part (From the County list)
});
```

Regarding the placement of the code; if you are going to use the exact same code, I would probably use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not help unfortunatly.

Comment: Check if the version of jQuery and SPServices you are using are compatible. In some of my projects I had to use SPServices-2013.01 instead of the latest (14.01)

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunatly this changes nothing in the result. The javascript just does not seem to load.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue where my parentColumn and childColumn were required fields. Once made them optional then it worked again. Not sure if SPServices has a way to deal with them if required.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.
Let me first explain how I found it: I recreated the scenario found at the [project wiki](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation), but without bothering about any extra options, like is this field required, whats the max length of this property and so on. 
After this I added the code from the linked wiki into the newform.aspx. After calling up this form in the browser I recieved some javascript errors in the developers console, which on my Orders list, I didn't.
As it turned out, I misspelled a column in my States list. I corrected it and the code worked.

Now, after having a working and a non working example in one SiteCollection, I compared the settings on the lists.
As it turned out, the columns for Category, Subcategory & Item on my Orders list were mandatory, where those on my CascadingTest list from the wiki, they were not.
After I unchecked "must contain values", the script run.

I'll leave this unanswered for a few days. May be someone comes up with an explanation to this.